# Generate access token by google login using oauth2

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

My front end in Angular JS.

It sends me google token after user logs in with gmail

In backend I verify the token and extract information from it as below

```
@csrf_exempt
def check(request):
CLIENT_ID = 'xxxxx'
try:
    json_data = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
    idinfo = id_token.verify_oauth2_token(json_data['google_token'], requests.Request(), CLIENT_ID)

    if idinfo['iss'] not in ['accounts.google.com', 'https://accounts.google.com']:
        raise ValueError('Wrong issuer.')

    print("idinfo")
    print(idinfo)
```

Now I got the user details here and want to generate an access token to access my API's for every request.

Is there any built in function from oauth2 to generate an access token.

Any suggestion that would help me.  Thanks.

Comment: The client does not generate an access token. It is requesting it from the server.

Comment: Yeah, How would I do that on my server side.

Comment: In most cases that should be done by the OAuth implementation you are using. There should be an endpoint to request a bearer token for example. Doing it manually is rather complex.

Comment: Is there any function in oauth2 to generate access token.

Comment: OAuth2 is a protocol it does not have functions. But any library implementing OAuth2 might have such a function.

Comment: Check the docs (step 5): https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/auth/web-app

Comment: please tell me which one to use.

Comment: But that is a flask implemented one.

Comment: Use this https://github.com/anupy/google-oauth This will give you complete core code of Google OAuth

Comment: How do you pass your mail details @anupyadav